# Convert base64 string to image in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a requirement where I am cropping the image using ng2-image cropper. But the output is of base64, I want to convert it to image source as I have to send it to some server.
I have searched but didn't found anything compatible with angular 4 .

Comment: Where exactly does Angular get in the way here? If you have your decoded Base64 (using whatever library) you can send it off to the server, no?

Comment: their is a requirement that i need to send it in image format only on the server

Comment: To de- or encode a base64 you can use the [corresponding function from javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

Comment: it is not working, getting error in that too

Comment: Can't understand negative votes here. Are you so in need of "deep troll" or "exclusive hater" badge from SO?

Comment: i can't understant the negative votes either :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it can be done by using conversion to Blob

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
     array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
  }
 return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
    type: 'image/jpg'
});
}

    enter code here

 var myFile:Blob=this.dataURItoBlob(myDataUri);
```

Comment: Hello, i am trying to do similar thing, can you please tell me how was your dataURI look like.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this another simple way to convert base64 to blob**

```
   fetch(base64)
    .then(res => {
      return res.blob();
    })
    .then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
    });
```